# Will chocolate cake be edible if I added one cup of water instead of two?

Tags: baking, cake

What will happen to chocolate cake if I added one cup of boiling water instead of two, and I did not realize it until it was baking? Will it be edible?

Comment: Edible yes, tasty remains to be seen.

Comment: My guess will be it will be really dry(or burnt) on the outside before the inside is fully cooked. you might want to lower the temperature and raise the baking time to accommodate for the drier batter.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the recipe you were using. We would have a better chance of correctly determining what outcome you might face.

Comment: @Eileen - How did your cake come out? Can you answer your own question?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't have affected the edibility of the cake....and there's no scope of the cake's being dry.... :)

Comment: Well, unless it comes out too hard to actually cut and eat.

Comment: @Jefromi Adding less than 1 cup or no water at all might cause it to be hard...... 